# How to fetch records from a specific record zone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, icloud, cloudkit

I'm building an app that allows users to manage their products in the cloud.
To do this, I have a Product Record type in iCloud. I use this record type for two purposes:

- To manage the products I have available, all stored in a dedicated **Products** record zone
- To save products I have stored in checks from customers. I have a separate **Checks** record zone, in which I save checks or 'receipts' from transactions made with customers. I use the Product record type here too, in order to keep track of what products are being sold.

Now I have one problem: When I try to fetch all products for my product manager, it also fetches the products from the **Checks** record zone - the zone containing the transactions and the products they contain. I obviously need to fetch only the products from the **Products** Record Zone.

There doesn't seem to be much reference for this on the internet, so I figured I'd post a question here for, also for future reference.

**Is there a way in CloudKit to fetch records from a specific record zone?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a CKQueryOperation and set the zoneID like this:

```
    let operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
    operation.zoneID = CKRecordZoneID(zoneName: "name", ownerName: "me")
```